# Which current ripple equation should I use? (Boost converter)

Tags: inductor, boost, converter, ripple

I am designing a boost converter for a microgrid as an university project. It is supposed to interface a 2.4kW 120V solar array (using MPPT) with a 380V DC bus. There will be other sources and loads connected to the bus.

My professor have told me to have 5% current ripple regulation for the converter. Therefore I am trying to choose a suitable inductor value, but I am stumped as there seem to be 2 equations to use.

Equation 1:
[image: TI instruments's Basic calculation of a Boost converter's power stage]
[image: Inductance values using equation 1]

**versus**

Equation 2:
[image: Some lecture notes on Boost converters]

[image: Inductance values using equation 2]

As you can see, I would very much prefer to use the values of equation 2 since they are much smaller than equation 1. My supervisor also told me not to overrate the inductor.  But I think I do need to confirm and understand the equations to use when interfacing between a bus and a solar array, which is why I am seeking advice from the experts here.

Comment: Do you need to document your decision process? if not, go for a simulation and see which fits best

Comment: I do need documentation in my final report. As for simulation purposes, I don't really know much about creating power buses in Matlab(only simulation software I have)..

Comment: @Mittens You also "have" CircuitLab (via this stackexchange!) and LtSpice. Both are free and would be much better suited to quickly simulate it.